# Conda solving environment freeze during docker build

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, conda

I am trying to activate conda env and install packages inside Docker container.
Everything works fine if I do it in interactive shell session inside container. However during build  conda install freezes on solving environment stages.

I guess that probably my conda env is not activated properly in Dockerfile, however I am not sure what exactly might be the problem.

If I use pip instead of conda it fails for mpi4py - and during shell inside container pip works fine

Updating conda does not help

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-base

RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-ml.list
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install curl python3 python3-pip

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV CONDA_DIR /opt/conda
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/conda.sh && \
     /bin/bash ~/conda.sh -b -p /opt/conda

ENV PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH
ARG CONDA_ENV=pipenv
ENV CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=$CONDA_ENV
RUN conda create -y -n pipenv python=3.8
RUN conda init bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
RUN echo "conda activate pipenv" >> ~/.bashrc

RUN conda config --append channels conda-forge
RUN conda install -c conda-forge setuptools==59.5.0 wheel
RUN conda install -c conda-forge einops==0.6.0 mpi4py==3.1.4
```

Comment: Why installing Anaconda? That is a huge bloat and Conda is slow. Start from something minimal and fast like micromamba or Mambaforge. The "freeze" is likely due to mixing Conda Forge channel with Anaconda - that almost never ends well. But more immediately, you are probably installing into **base** despite your efforts: you need `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]`.